# NSCollectionView doesn't popup context menu?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, events, nscollectionview

I've bounded the menu to the NSCollectionView in interface builder. But when I CTRL+click (right click) on it the menu is not showing.

I've tried adding some method to the NSCollectionView subclass. None of them is invoked:

```
+ (NSMenu*)defaultMenu
- (NSMenu *)menuForEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent
- (void)rightMouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
- (void)sendEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

The only method which is invoked is:

```
- (NSView *)hitTest:(NSPoint)aPoint
```

Which means that the NSCollectionView receives the mouse events.

I've also tried to add the same methods to the subclass of NSCollectionViewItem, and the result is the same. Only `hitTest:` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@interface MyCollectionView : NSView
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
@end

@implementation MyCollectionView

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{

    NSMenu *theMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contextual Menu"];
    [theMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"Beep" action:@selector(beep) keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:0];
    [theMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"Honk" action:@selector(honk) keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:1];

    [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:theMenu withEvent:theEvent forView:self];

    [super mouseDown:theEvent];

}

-(void)beep{

}

-(void)honk{

}

@end
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The mouseDown method is called, but the menu doesn't popup. But I don't get your answer: you have override the superclass method with any custom code in it, so what's the difference?

Comment: I thought your problem is that the mousedown won't get called. With it getting called it should be easy to display the contextmenu. I update my answer in a minute

Comment: I see, ok thanks. However this is a workaround, right? It should popup automatically.

Comment: ok thanks. I've added if ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSControlKeyMask) to check if it's right click (or ctrl+click).

Comment: I just checked the Apple Docs. It says it's one of three possible implementations. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/DisplayContextMenu.html

Comment: Ah ok. So not so workaround after all. Is maybe because NSCollectionView is an old class? I saw a new version is going to be published soon.

Comment: I don't think that the problem is the age of the class. I just think you are missing something in your original implementation. But if it works now, everything should be fine. But i saw a WWDC Video recently about changes to the NSCollectionView, too. I think they changed the design of it for osx 10.11+

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with the "new" `NSCollectionView`. The contextual menu is set up in the xib, and it is actually correctly triggered by an actual right-click on the mouse, and also by double-finger tab on the trackpad (if the user has set that option in the System Preferences), but not by control-click. Thus it seems like a legitimate bug or limitation with `NSCollectionView`, maybe dependent on how it is set up.

In any case, here is a shorter solution, this one in Swift, that assumes you have otherwise set up the contextual menu using the `menu` outlet for the collection view (or you have it set up as outlined in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/DisplayContextMenu.html)).

You will need to create a subclass of `NSCollectionView` and choose the subclass for the collection view in the xib. Here is the code for the subclass:

```
import Cocoa

class MyCollectionView: NSCollectionView {

    /// Fixes the behavior of collection view with control-click, that does not properly trigger the contextual menu.
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)
        if event.type == .rightMouseDown || event.modifierFlags.contains(.control) {
            rightMouseDown(with: event)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: One should select the item that's clicked on (and deselect others if the item wasn't already selected).

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the NSCollectionView

```
class OSCollectionView: NSCollectionView {

    
    override func menu(for event: NSEvent) -> NSMenu? {
        print("menu() called")
        let menu = NSMenu()
        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Create a clone", action: #selector(clone(_:)), keyEquivalent: ""))
        return menu
    }
    
    
    @objc
    func clone(_ sender: Any){
        //editDelegate?.terminateAndReplace(self)
        print("Clone item")
    }
}
```